# host asp.net 4.0 site in windows server 2008, iis6

Tags: .net-4.0, iis-6, asp.net-4.0, windows-server-2003

I want to host a asp.net 4.0 application in windows server 2003. I referred may sites and followed the below steps as per the suggestion given in multiple sites.

1. Installed .net Framework 4.0 client
2. Installed .net Framework 4.0 Full
3. Tried to register .net 4.0 for my website using below

   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -SN W3SVC/{siteid}/ROOT
4. I got error when I use ablove command like below
   "the error indicates that IIS is in 64 bit mode, while this application is a 32 bit application and thus not compatible"
5. To resolve the above problem I used the below command to enable 32bit application

   cscript.exe adsutil.vbs set W3SVC/AppPools/Enable32BitAppOnWin64 1
6. after step5 I can register framework using step 3.

still site showing error. 
like" server applcation unavailable"

Can you plesae guide me to resolve this?

Thanks,
Haridharan. R

Answer (score 0):

I have done the asp.net 4.0 site deployment in windows server 2003 by the following steps.

1. Undone the above steps I have mentioned.
2. Install framework 4.0
3. Create new application pool (if there is no option to create, please ignore this)
4. Open IIS6 -> Web Service Extension -> "Allow" framework 2.0 and 4.0
5. Add your website in IIS.
6. right click on your site -> properties -> go to "home directory" tab -> select the new application pool you have created.(if there is no option, please ignore this)
7. go to "ASP.NET" tab -> change the framework version to 4.0
8. browse your site.